# token creation in postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to access the webpage via Postman.

I have my own credentials; "barcode" and "belge_no" are the variables that create "`_token`".

_token is needed to access data on the server, How can I automate Postman to create, and use _token for future "`barcode`" and "`belge_no`"

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8367.png)

Comment: What kind of authentication is setup on that site?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can check from the following link. https://covid-19.gov.ct.tr/